# I want to manage CRUD on a list with hibernate. Is this a good practice?

Tags: hibernate

I want to hold a list and update its changes on a database.
Basically,
 in order to save - I iterate all the objects and save each one.
In order to delete - Each time an objhect is removed I keep a copy of that object for later in another list. 
When I save I also iterate it and delete those element.

```
private boolean saveAll() {
    Session session = null;
    boolean successful = false;
    try {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        for (myObject myO : myObjectsList) {
            session.save(myO);
        }

        for (myObject removedObject : toBeRemovedList) {
            session.delete(removedObject);
        }

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        successful = true;
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        successful = false;
    } finally {
        if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    return successful;
}
```

Now I plan to call it like this:

```
if (saveAll()){
    toBeRemovedList.clear()
}
```

Any comments ?

Thanks.

Comment: did you tried the below answer?I did not see any comments. Please upvote/ accept answers it it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much you can do with the save. But the delete functionality can be improved by using the below `HQL`,

```
Query q = createQuery("delete from YourObjectName where id in (:idList) ");
q.setParameterList("idList", idList);
q.executeUpdate();
```

You can find the java docs [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameterList%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Collection%29).

Here only one query will be executed to delete all the items in the list.